# How do I support both .Net 6 and .Net Framwork 4.7.2 with my nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I'm creating a class library project that is packaged to Nuget.org ([Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OnePlatforms.AWU/) [Github](https://github.com/One-Platforms/OnePlatforms.AWU)). Right now when I create the nuget package the only runtime it supports is .Net 6.

I need it to also support .Net Framework 4.7.2 as well for use in a WinForms application.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Actually, what I want to ask is how can I add .NET Framework support to a package that only supports .NET Core.

Comment: Target .net standard

Comment: You could also compile it multiple times. Then include both assemblies in the package

Comment: Add .NET Framework to targets. Possibly add some conditional compilation directives.

Comment: [some docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/multiple-target-frameworks-project-file) to start.

Comment: Instead of using `<TargetFramework>` in your csproj, you need to update it to `<TargetFrameworks>` and as others have said, include a `netstandard2.0` target alongside .net 6. There are tremendous benefits to multi-target compilation, especially when targeting later .net versions like .net 6, due to so many core libraries having native sdk support. As a result, you need fewer nuget packages if you do some conditional compilation and your .net 6 target version WILL see better performance overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your class library to target .Net Standard. Ideally .Net Standard 2.0 as that's the highest version of .Net Standard that .Net Framework 4.7.2 supports.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0

You don't say right now how you create the nuget package, but if it's with `dotnet pack` then the resulting nupkg file should have the correct target runtime once you switch your project file over. If you have a nuspec file then just adjust the folder where files are copied to.

Comment: It sounds like this would work; however, when I click project properties, under Target Framework, the only choices in the dropdown are .NET 5, .NET 6, and various versions of .NET Core.  I also tried changing the target OS to Windows, that did not help.  So how do I change the target framework to Standard?  I should add, I do have .net 4.7x, 4.8x installed...

Comment: @JayImerman edit the csproj file directly.